# Reduce Load time of Service Console in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, service-cloud-console, service

I would like to reduce the load time of the service console because of which agents are annoyed.

I have one lighting component which gets data from server with soql and then data is bind to wrapper class, which is used to display data.

Currently it takes on average 6.6 sec to load. Is it normal time or on the higher side?

Any inputs on this will be really helpful.

Here is the Code: 
[image: This is how Service Console looks like]
=====Component====

```
<aura:attribute name="quotes" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="tripId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="disableTripButton" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<!-- EMP API component -->
<lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi" />

<!-- Holds the streaming event subscription --> 
<aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Map" />
<!--aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" /-->
<aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="/topic/CaseOpportunity" />
```

```
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                        <h1>
                            <span>Plutus</span>
                            <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Booking Overview">Booking Overview</span>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-page-header__col-actions">
        <div class="slds-page-header__controls">
            <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                <button disabled="{!v.disableTripButton}" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-button_stateful slds-not-selected" aria-live="assertive" onclick="{!c.openActionWindow}" >
                    <span class="slds-text-not-selected">View Plutus Trip</span>
                </button>
                <!--button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New</button>
            <ui:button label="View Plutus Trip" press="{!c.openActionWindow}" class="slds-button slds-float_right"/-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td>
            <!--ui:button label="GoTo Plutus Trip" press="{!c.openActionWindow}" class="slds-button slds-float_right"/-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--th><td><b>Name</b></td></th-->
        <th><td><b>Supplier Name</b></td></th>
        <th><td><b>Type</b></td></th>
        <th><td><b>Status</b></td></th>
        <th><td><b>Sales Price</b></td></th>
        <th><td><b>Departure Date</b></td></th>
        <th><td><b>Arrival Date</b></td></th>
    </tr>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.quotes}"  var="quote">

        <tr class="slds-hint-parent quoteRow" onclick="{!c.switchChildRows}" id="{!quote.parentID}" aura:id="{!quote.parentID}">
            <!--td> {!quote.parentName}</td-->
        </tr>
       <aura:iteration items="{!quote.lstSegment}" var="seg">
             <tr class="{!'slds-hint-parent segmentRow  ' + quote.parentID}">
                 <!--td><div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!seg.segID}</div></td-->
                 <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!seg.supplierName}</div></td>
                 <td><div class="slds-truncate" title=""><lightning:badge label="{!seg.recordTypeName}"/> </div></td>
                  <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!seg.status}</div></td>
                 <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!seg.costPrice + ' '}{!seg.cur}</div></td>
                 <td><ui:outputDate aura:id="oDate" value="{!seg.departureDate}"/></td> 
                 <td><ui:outputDate aura:id="oDate" value="{!seg.arrivalDate}"/></td> 

            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </aura:iteration>
</table>
```

=====Controller====

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.getBooking");
    action.setParams({ caseID : component.get("v.recordId") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('data::',response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.quotes", data);
        /*    if( data[0] && data[0].tripID )
                component.set("v.tripId", data[0].tripID);
            else
                component.set("v.disableTripButton", True); */
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    var getTripId = component.get("c.getTripIdFromCase");
    getTripId.setParams({ caseID : component.get("v.recordId") });
    getTripId.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('data::',response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.tripId", data);

        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getTripId);

    //Get the empApi component
    const empApi = component.find('empApi');
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    // Uncomment below line to enable debug logging (optional)
    //empApi.setDebugFlag(true);

    // Register error listener and pass in the error handler function
    empApi.onError($A.getCallback(error => {
        // Error can be any type of error (subscribe, unsubscribe...)
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    }));

    // Get the channel from the input box
    const channel = component.get("v.channel");
    // Replay option to get new events
    const replayId = -1;

    // Subscribe to an event
    empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
        // Process event (this is called each time we receive an event)
        //console.log('Received event ', JSON.stringify(eventReceived));
        if(eventReceived.data.sobject.Id == recordId){
            console.log('Case Opportunity Changed Captured');
          $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            console.log('==EventCaptured');

            $A.enqueueAction(action); 
            $A.enqueueAction(getTripId);
        }
    }))
    .then(subscription => {
        // Confirm that we have subscribed to the event channel.
        // We haven't received an event yet.
        //console.log('Subscribed to channel ', subscription.channel);
        // Save subscription to unsubscribe later
        component.set('v.subscription', subscription);
    });        
},

switchChildRows : function(component, event, helper) {
 /*   console.log('switchChildRows::');
    var test = event.currentTarget.id ;
    console.log('TEST2 --->' + test);

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(test);
    console.log("elements.length: " + elements.length);
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
    } */
}, 
openActionWindow : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('openActionWindow');
    console.log('TRIPDID:', component.get("v.tripId"));
    if( component.get("v.tripId") != 0 )
        window.open("https://pegasus.dreamlines.local/PlutusTrip/Details/" + component.get("v.tripId"));
    else {

        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Warning!",
            "message": "There is no related trip for this Case.",
            "type" : "Warning" 
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }

}
```

})

=====ApexController====

```
public with sharing class LDSController {

public class BookingWrapper{

    @AuraEnabled
    public ID parentID{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String tripID{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String parentName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<SegmentsWrapper> lstSegment{get;set;}
}

public class SegmentsWrapper{

    @AuraEnabled
    public ID segID{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String cur{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String status{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date arrivalDate{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date departureDate {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public ID supplierId{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal costPrice{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String supplierName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String recordTypeName{get;set;}
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<BookingWrapper> getBooking(Id caseID){

    List<BookingWrapper> lstBookingWrappers = new List<BookingWrapper>();
    map<String, Booking_Segment__c> mapBS = new map<String, Booking_Segment__c>();
    map<Decimal,List<Booking_Segment__c>> mapParentSegToBs = new map<Decimal, list<Booking_Segment__c>>();

  //  try{
    String tripID;
    Case objCase = [SELECT id,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.Non_Plutus_Trip_ID__c , Opportunity__r.Booking__c FROM Case Where Id =: caseID];
    if(objCase.Opportunity__c != Null)    
        tripID = objCase.Opportunity__r.Non_Plutus_Trip_ID__c  != Null ? String.valueof(objCase.Opportunity__r.Non_Plutus_Trip_ID__c ) : ' ';

    List<Booking__c> lstBookings = [SELECT Name,id,Customer_Message__c, (SELECT id, Arrival_Date__c,Sales_Price__c, Cost_Price__c,Name, Supplier__r.Name, Departure_Date__c,
                                                                         CurrencyIsoCode,RecordType.Name,Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c ,toLabel(Status__c), Segment_Type__c From Booking_Segments__r where Status__c  != '8' and Supplier__c != null
                                                                                and Segment_Type__c != 'Cancellation Fee') 
                            From Booking__c Where ID =: objCase.Opportunity__r.Booking__c];

   for(Booking__c oB : lstBookings) { 
       for(Booking_Segment__c oBS : oB.Booking_Segments__r) {
          /* if(oBS.Segment_Type__c == 'Flight'){
                if(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c != Null && !mapParentSegToBs.containsKey(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c)) 
                    mapParentSegToBs.put(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c, new list<Booking_Segment__c>{oBS});
                else 
                    mapParentSegToBs.get(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c).add(oBS);    
           } */
           mapBS.put(oBS.Name, oBS);
       }
   }

   for(Booking__c oBooking : lstBookings) {
        BookingWrapper oBW = new BookingWrapper();
        oBW.tripID = tripID;
        oBW.lstSegment = new List<SegmentsWrapper>();
        oBW.parentName = oBooking.Name;
        oBW.parentID = oBooking.Id;
        List<SegmentsWrapper> lstSegments = new List<SegmentsWrapper>();
        for(Booking_Segment__c oBS : oBooking.Booking_Segments__r) {

            SegmentsWrapper sw = new SegmentsWrapper();
            sw.name = oBS.Name;
            if(oBS.Supplier__r.Name != Null)
                sw.supplierName = oBS.Supplier__r.Name;
            sw.status = oBS.Status__c;  
            sw.segID = oBS.ID;  
            sw.arrivalDate =  Date.valueOf(oBS.Arrival_Date__c);
            sw.departureDate = Date.valueOf(oBS.Departure_Date__c);
            sw.supplierId = oBS.Supplier__c;
            sw.costPrice = oBS.Sales_Price__c;
            sw.recordTypeName = oBS.RecordType.Name;
            sw.cur = oBS.CurrencyIsoCode;
            if(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c == Null) {
                lstSegments.add(sw);
            } else {
                if(oBS.Segment_Type__c == 'flight') {
                    if(oBS.Segment_Type__c != mapBS.get(String.valueof(oBS.Plutus_Parent_Segment_ID__c)).Segment_Type__c)
                        lstSegments.add(sw);
                } else {
                    lstSegments.add(sw);
                }
            }
        }
        oBW.lstSegment = lstSegments;
        lstBookingWrappers.add(oBW);  
    }
/* }catch(exception ex){ 

        system.debug(ex.getlineNumber() + 'LDSController::' );
        Logger.getInstance().writeLogs();
    } */

return lstBookingWrappers;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Decimal getTripIdFromCase(Id caseID) {

    if([Select Opportunity__c From Case Where ID =: caseID].Opportunity__c != NULL) {
        Decimal dec = [Select Opportunity__r.Non_Plutus_Trip_ID__c From Case Where ID =: caseID].Opportunity__r.Non_Plutus_Trip_ID__c;
        return   dec != NULL ? dec : 0;  
    }
    return 0;

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Without looking at your code it is difficult to predict

Comment: nothing much is there to share my code, on init I call do soql for the related records and display them using wrapper as said.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code anyhow?  6.6 seconds seems like a very long time for a simple SOQL query. I'm assuming your SOQL query had a lot of `WHERE` clauses and tons of records to filter through?

Comment: @BrianMiller I have added it.

Comment: I don't see anything too obvious.  For your main `getBooking` method, consider using `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`.  If you're bookings aren't changing so quickly, then this will cache the results and help performance